# Selection rules for atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, spectroscopy, atoms

I was told that in atoms the transitions between the energy levels are restricted by so called selection rules. For example if $J$ (resp. $J'$) denotes the  (angular plus spin) momentum of the atom before (resp. after) emission of a photon then they satisfy
$$J'-J=0,\pm 1.$$

**Question 1.** Is this selection rule precise or approximate?

**Question 2.** How to prove it?

**Question 3.** Are there other selection rules in atoms?

A reference will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "precise or approximate." If by "approximate" you mean to allow the possibility that $\Delta J = 0.9 \approx 1$: no, that's absolutely not allowed.  The angular quantum numbers are constrained to be integers; proving this occupies about a month of an intro-quantum course.

If by "approximate" you mean "are transitions with $\Delta J = \pm 2$ secretly allowed under some circumstances," the answer is *yes*. See for instance [this summary table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule#Summary_table). Your selection rules are for "dipole" transitions, where the angular momentum is carried away by the photon's spin. But there are also "quadrupole" and higher transitions, where the atom and the final-state photon have nonzero orbital angular momentum.  Constructing the linked summary table would be an appropriate assignment for a graduate-level quantum mechanics course.

Comment: Thank you.  I meant the second option.

Answer (score 0):

To expand/simplify on Rob's answer, since the transition is caused by the emission of a photon and spin by definition remains conserved, we can use the fact that if $J$ was the initial momentum and a photon that can have a spin of $\pm1$ is emitted, the vector addition laws state that $J'$ can only acquire values of $J+0, J\pm 1$.

Comment: As far as I understand not the spin conserved but the sum of spin and orbital momentum. But the preservation of this sum is an exact law which holds under all circumstances and, as far as I understand, is weaker than the mentioned selection rule.